# Multiple enqueue in retrofit causing out of memory error?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, retrofit, retrofit2

Am doing my project using retrofit2. When my Call goes on failure i repeat same call again.Repeation of this call made my app to force close.
When i look on log i got error log, which is given below. I felt this is caused by multiple enqueue to same Call. So i did that before enqueus i called cancel. But its not working. getting same force close.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.SocialMob, PID: 27846
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (stack size 16384 bytes) failed: Try again
at java.lang.VMThread.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1029)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:920)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1338)
at okhttp3.Dispatcher.enqueue(Dispatcher.java:112)
at okhttp3.RealCall.enqueue(RealCall.java:78)
at okhttp3.RealCall.enqueue(RealCall.java:70)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.enqueue(OkHttpCall.java:104)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.enqueue(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:58)
at com.SocialMob.Activities.SplashActivity.VersionCheck(SplashActivity.java:184)
at com.SocialMob.Activities.SplashActivity.access$500(SplashActivity.java:38)
at com.SocialMob.Activities.SplashActivity$1.onFailure(SplashActivity.java:177)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$2.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:75)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid that approach, as it would make it a recursive call. Instead you should check the cause in the failure function first and then retry. Also fix the number of retry times.

Comment: its because of network error, what should i do now ?

Comment: there are many types of network error. 

1. If it's 404 then there is nothing you can do except notify the user about it. 

2. If it 500 then you should retry.

Comment: retry makes my app force close

Comment: Try call.cancel() before enque the retry call.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Retrofit 2.0.2, and i have this tag in my manifest file:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

I am retrying on failure like this:

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<AudioResponse> call, Throwable error) {
    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
        SetErrorContent();
    }
    Log.e("Error", error.getMessage() + "");

    call.cancel();
    call.clone().enqueue(this);
}
```

It is not crashing.Give it a try.