# Out of Memory Error for retrofit2 calls in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have a call to a WebAPI that sends back a small amount of JSON string. it's not even 1MB. But why is it, that I get an error of Out of Memory when the response comes in? Even the fetching from the URL takes a long time probably because it is trying to download a large file that I cannot see why.

From what I can surmise, the WebApi must have logged other stuff so when it is called, the rest goes with the reply. The WebAPI goes into the `response.isSuccessful` part but the response is too large so the application crashes.

My implementation is below:

```
private fun getEntryInfAndTollDue(plateNumber: String) {
        val pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)
        val current = LocalDateTime.now()
        val formatted = current.format(formatter)

        getEntryInfoAndTollDue.requestEntryInfoAndTollDueParam.tagNumber = ""
        getEntryInfoAndTollDue.requestEntryInfoAndTollDueParam.defaultEntryPlaza = Integer.parseInt(userData!!.defaultPlaza.toString())
        getEntryInfoAndTollDue.requestEntryInfoAndTollDueParam.exitPlaza = Integer.parseInt(userData!!.plaza.toString())
        getEntryInfoAndTollDue.requestEntryInfoAndTollDueParam.trxnDateTime = formatted

        getEntryInfoAndTollDue.requestEntryInfoAndTollDueParam.tid = ""
        getEntryInfoAndTollDue.requestEntryInfoAndTollDueParam.epc = ""
        getEntryInfoAndTollDue.requestEntryInfoAndTollDueParam.plateNumeber = plateNumber

        getEntryInfoAndTollDue.config.uri = "http://" + webServiceProperties.uri + ":" + webServiceProperties.port +"/iTag/GetEntryInfoAndTollDue"

        val hashedValue = getEntryInfoAndTollDue.getHashedValue()
        val scheme = getEntryInfoAndTollDue.requestHeaderEntryInfoParam.sessionID
        val parameter = ":$hashedValue"
        val authorizationToken = scheme + parameter

        val gson = Gson()
        val rawString = gson.toJson(getEntryInfoAndTollDue.requestEntryInfoAndTollDueParam)
        val randomKey = getEntryInfoAndTollDue.config.randomKey
        val strRFIDtrns = _3Dess.EnctyptTxt(randomKey, rawString, newEntryInfo.config.keyOffSet)

        val webService = WebServiceBuilder.buildService(WebService::class.java)
        CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
            val uri = getEntryInfoAndTollDue.config.uri
            val call = webService.getEntryInfoAndTollDueFromWebService(uri, authorizationToken, "application/json", strRFIDtrns!!)
            var responseFromApi: String? = null
            if (!call.isExecuted) {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog(context)
                progressDialog!!.setMessage("Fetching Entry Information. Please wait...")
                progressDialog!!.setCancelable(false)
                progressDialog!!.show()
                call.enqueue(object: Callback<ResponseBody> {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                        progressDialog!!.dismiss()
                        Log.i("RESPONSE", "ON FAILURE")
                        responseFromApi = t.message
                        var toastHelper = ToastHelper.getInstance(context!!).failedToastLong(t.message!!.toString(), activity!!)
                        toastHelper.show()
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            progressDialog!!.dismiss()
                            val token = response.body()?.string()
                            Log.i("RESPONSE", response.body()?.string())
                            val gson: Gson = Gson()
                            val result = gson.fromJson(token, EntryInfoAndTollDueResult::class.java)
                            val decryptedValue = getEntryInfoAndTollDue.decrypt(result!!.message)
                            responseEntryInfoAndTollDue = gson.fromJson(decryptedValue, ResponseEntryInfoAndTollDue::class.java)
                            Log.i("TAG", responseEntryInfoAndTollDue.message)
                        } else {
                            val res = response.errorBody()!!.string()
                            Log.e("RESPONSE", "ON ERROR: " + res)
                            progressDialog!!.dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

**WebService**

```
 @POST
    fun getEntryInfoAndTollDueFromWebService(
        @Url url: String,
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
        @Header("Accept") acpt: String,
        @Body data: String
    ):retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody>
```

**WebServiceBuilder**

```
object WebServiceBuilder {
    private const val URL = "http://192.168.100.143:5000/"

    private val okHttp = OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    private val builder = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttp.build())

    private val retrofit = builder.build()

    fun <T> buildService(serviceType: Class<T>): T {
        return retrofit.create(serviceType)
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can just get the response of the server and not the other stuff?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple enqueue in retrofit causing out of memory error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155783/multiple-enqueue-in-retrofit-causing-out-of-memory-error)

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the OOM exception?